# Update data in yii using model object

Tags: yii

I am New to YII
Trying to update value of user using below code

```
public function actionProfile(){

    $model = new Users;

    if(isset($_POST['update'])){            

            $model->findByPk(Yii::app()->session['user_id']);
            $model->user_name = $_POST['Users']['user_name'];
            $model->update();           
            $this->refresh();

            //echo '<pre>';
            //print_r($_POST);die;
        }
}
```

When I use below it worked, I couldn't get what is the problem with above code it is also doing it same way. Please help.
Now my question is WHY I can not update the content using `$model` object of model In the above code.

```
if(isset($_POST['update'])){

        $user = Users::model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->session['user_id']);

        $user->user_name = $_POST['Users']['user_name'];
        $user->update();

        $this->refresh();

        //echo '<pre>';
        //print_r($_POST);die;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you did not assign `user_id` to `$model` to update. Try something like below.

```
$model = $model->findByPk(Yii::app()->session['user_id']); //This line
$model->user_name = $_POST['Users']['user_name'];
$model->update();
```

Since you did not assign `user_id` (pk), it is considered as a new record. As a result `update` is interrupted. I also suggest you to add error reporting like this

```
try{
     $model->update();
}catch (Exception $ex){
     die($ex->getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As my knowledge, when you need to update model data, you have to just load an existing model, no need to creat a new one.That's why the second one is worked for you.

```
Users::model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->session['user_id']);// loading existing model

$model = new Users; //creating a new model instance
```